# PHP in combination with MySQL is extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I am currently experiencing slowness with one of my servers. It is running an apache2 server with PHP and MySQL. The MySQL server is hosted on the same machine as the webserver itself.

Whenever I request a PHP file containing MySQL queries the page needs approximately 24 seconds to show up. While requesting the page the CPU usage of apache2 goes up to 11% (!) which is very much in comparison to what it used to be a week ago.

Non-PHP files or PHP files without MySQL queries are showing up immediately.

What could be causing the problems with scripts containing MySQL queries?
I was unable to find any useful information inside the apache error logs.

Comment: do you have access to the MySQL logs?

Comment: I have access to the entire server. Unfortunately I'm unsure where the logs are being saved under Debian. The directory /var/log/mysql is empty, thus I assume it's storing them elsewhere.

And the files /var/log/mysql.err and mysql.log are empty.

Comment: Does query size effect the response time at all? That is, if you write a simple identity that doesn't touch any tables does it still take half a minute to respond?

Comment: I tried to do a couple of MySQL queries manually and they responded really fast when I logged in to the MySQL server via a terminal. They are very slow when I do them via a PHP script though, it takes ages to respond.

Comment: Make an isolated PHP page with just db connection code and a single query and run it then run the same query in the terminal, see if there is any difference in speed...

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I created an isolated PHP page on a different virtual host and it loaded very fast. It seems like the issue is related to something else than PHP+MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql console

```
show full processlist;  <-- to show what are the current SQL
```

To check where is the log file:-

```
show variables like '%log%'; <-- to show mysql variables
```

When doing query benchmark / testing, always remember to turn off query cache, using :-

```
set session query_cache_type=off;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. show full processlist returned two rows - apparently the processlist query itself and a query from a site of mine: | 59 | root | localhost | db1 | Sleep   |   20 |       | NULL
| Time: 20 seems to be fairly high.

Comment: sleep is sleep zzzzZZZZ ... you should open some of your slow pages, and do show full processlist at the same time for comparison.

Comment: Well but it seems like the page finally loads after this sleep entry disappeared. I tested it with a slower page from a wordpress blog.

Comment: did you site connect to any external resources? such as your wordpress is hosted at another network or so ? Sleep state is the mysql connection is opened, but is idle, waiting for next query.

Comment: The wordpress blog is hosted on the same server as well.

Comment: any other external resources? examine all the table index `select * from information_schema.STATISTICS where CARDINALITY is null;`, if you getting tables with NULL CARDINALITY yet the table is not empty (and is myisam), do an `optimize table $table_name;`

Comment: I can't think of any external resources.
I got several tables with NULL CARDINALITY, but those tables were in the database 'mysql'. I executed an optimize for all of them but it didn't really improve the performance.

Comment: triple check on the external resources, such as grabbing information from facebook, twitter ... etc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint - I removed some code from my site embedding an RSS feed from my word press blog (which is hosted on the same machine but slowed the other site down as well). So thanks to you I know that an issue with wordpress has to be the reason for the bad performance which already helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

database queries take time to run, and each query involves opening up at least one file. file access is slow.

you can speed up the requests by running the database in RAM instead of from the hard-drive, but the real answer is probably to cache as much as you can so you're doing as little database querying as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the site used to run really fast like a week ago. All of sudden it's very slow though, so I assume some kind of timeout is triggered? I lack the background knowledge though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the mysql database is greater then 2GB (or 4GB) because of some cms logging function and exceed a file size limit.

Comment: I googled for a query to obtain the database size and it seems like it's only about 2.1 MB small.